# Pandas: Remove Row Based on Applying Function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, and it has a column called `_text`.  I want to remove all rows where applying `sentence_count` to the value in `_text` column is not 0.

How would I go about this?

Normally with Pandas, I do something like:

```
result_df = result_df[result_df['_text'] != '']
```

But now I'm not just using the value in `result_df['_text`], I'm filtering based on the value calculated by a function...

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you use `DataFrame.dropna()`?

Answer (score 12):

If the function takes the sentence as its sole argument,

```
result_df[result_df['_text'].apply(sentence_count) != 0]
```